# su <user> vs su - <user> with respect to .exrc

Tags: login

Given 2 users in the same group

```
myuser:grp1
anotheruser:grp1
```

I have some Function key assignments in my personal .exrc file that I need to work the same way under both user logins. I have set 664 permissions to my .exrc and copied and set the other users .exrc the same way. My tmp folder has 777 permissions and is in the same group

the F10/11/12 keys specific commands from .exrc

```
map ^AI :1,$w! $HOME/tmp/tmp.tmp^M 
map ^AJ :'k,.w! $HOME/tmp/tmp.tmp^M
map ^AK :r $HOME/tmp/tmp.tmp^Mk
```

issue:

```
su - anotheruser
```

picks up the anotheruser .exrc but is using it's local tmp folder

```
su anotheruser
```

doesn't appear to use either .exrc as the F keys are doing something totally different and returns the following error:

> ex: 0602-054 No alternate file name to substitute for the # character.

I could force the anotheruser .exrc to explicitly point to my tmp folder and use su - but then there are other OS specific settings that are missing from my .profile and .kshrc files which I am not prepared to provide to the other user

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good use case for symlinks.  (This assumes you have `root` access.)

Put the `.exrc` file somewhere world-readable.  Possibly `/usr/local/share/`, although actually I think `/usr/etc/` would be appropriate.

```
sudo mv -i ~/.exrc /usr/etc/
```

`chown` it to root and set the permissions to 644.

```
cd /usr/etc/
sudo chown root:root .exrc
sudo chmod 644 .exrc
```

Create a symlink in your home directory like so:

```
ln -s /usr/etc/.exrc ~/.exrc
```

And in anotheruser's home directory as well:

```
ln -s /usr/etc/.exrc ~anotheruser/.exrc
```

---

You will still need to use `su - anotheruser` or `su -l anotheruser`, as you can see from the man page:

> ```
>    -, -l, --login
>           make  the  shell  a  login  shell, clears all envvars except for
>           TERM, initializes HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME and PATH
> ```

Since `.exrc` is loaded depending on your `$HOME` environment variable, that needs to be set appropriately for this to work.